# How to compute correlation function and length for a given lattice configuration?

Tags: condensed-matter, phase-transition, ising-model

Focusing on the Ising model, for a given lattice configuration of up and down spins (say square or triangular lattice), and a given interaction type (ferromagnetic or antiferro), how can one compute the correlation function as well as the correlation length?

Comment: This question is way too broad to be answered. The standard analytical techniques include mean-field theory and the renormalization group. A nice textbook going over the theory is by Goldenfeld "Lectures On Phase Transitions And The Renormalization Group." If you want to calculate these things computationally, you should look into Monte Carlo calculations. I don't do Monte Carlo calculations myself, but there should be plenty of resources you can find with a quick google.

Comment: If you are interested in computationally studying quantum spin Hamiltonians, you might want to take a look at the lecture notes by Sandvik, https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.3281